# Combining Images Vertically with a horizontal offset

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-montage

@ https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

Reading these posts I was able to join images vertically, however if you see the result ..bottom image needs a slight pixel offset (because its y-axis is 2-figure value as compared to upper image having y-axis of 3-figure, x-axis is same & at constant interval)

If I can just give bottom picture a slight nudge to the right, x-axis will appear more appropriate

Individual images (same dimension)
[image]
[image]

Result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a little 10 pixel transparent *"filler"* image to the left of the bottom one like this:

```
convert -background none top.png \
  \( -size 10x10 xc:none bottom.png +append \) -append result.png
```

[image]

I have made the filler green below so you can see it.

### [image]

So, by way of explanation, `+append` will append side-by-side with the first image on the left and subsequent ones to the right, whilst `-append` will append top-to-bottom with the first image at the top and subsequent images below.

If you want to append to the left, or above, use the operators like `-reverse` to reverse the order of the frames.

Comment: Thanks ..can you make me understand this portion `\( -size 10x10 xc:none bottom.png +append \)` & why a space after `(` & before `-size` is required

Comment: It is called *"aside processing"* and it has to be in parentheses (brackets) with spaces as I showed. Inside there I create a 10x10 transparent image and then append the `bottom.png` image to its right side making a single combined image when I exit the parentheses. Then that resulting image is appended below the top image.